# Running multiple 4-wire bipolar stepper motors without drivers etc

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I need to use about 120 motors for an arts project. My budget is limited, as are my skills.
I need linear motion. I have found well-priced stepper units driving lead screw and nuts at sensible prices.
I only need simple up and down motion to the limit of travel.

I propose using limit switches at either end for this.
I have seen videos showing stepper units being run from a 12 volt transformer using a capacitor, which allows forward and reverse operation.

My question is -

Is the power output using this method sufficient to drive the lead screws effectively?

The motors are 4-9 volt or 12 volt depending on seller. The following data is for conventional use with a driver and controller:

- 800 mA per phase.
- Bipolar 4 wire
- 3 mm thread diameter : thread rod pitch +-0.5 mm
- Pull out thrust 500 gm

Any help/advice will be much appreciated.

---

Updates:

Hi Schnedan

Whilst I have good electro-mechanical skills, I have no knowledge of coding hence this is an attractive option.
All relays are closely spaced and fed by heavy duty bus bars.
All start in fully down position - lower limit switch to be overridden by low coil current relay. Central control by a pair of 81 LED sequential programmers. NE555 and CD4017 creating a wave action. Return to lower position centrally controlled for all units simultaneously, via heavy duty relay. Apologies for poor info and would welcome any suggestions.

---

Hi Brian

Good suggestion, but there's a long lead time from order to delivery of units from China (about 6 weeks) so would appreciate any top tips.

Hi Graham
Good suggestion but none available with built in lead screw , captive nut , guide rails and chassis .Steppers however are plentiful and affordable as a complete unit - see e bay .
Thanks for Arduino suggestion - I want and need to embrace this but at the moment need to stay within my skill set .
Best Tony

Hi Chris
Thanks for your observations.
I have a number of constraints

1. Money - this is a big project for me with a very tight budget.
   The units I’ve sourced cost £7 each and are very well engineered and have sufficient travel for my needs.

2.Time - I’m single handed - modifying 120 units with DC motors ( which I may have to do if plan A doesn’t work ), will be time consuming and add significant extra cost which is a problem.

3.My “driver “which is a pair of 81 LED chaser Units, using NE555 and CD4017 chips is cheap and simple to build , and I’m planning to use a”relay based enabling system as you suggest .

4.I have good electro mechanical skills but no knowledge at all of Arduino and code etc . I don’t have the time for a new and probably steep learning curve so I want to stick with what I’m good at much as I would love to expand my skill base .

5.The “wave” I want needs to be very slow with a long travel time .Each unit has a three second time for the full range of movement  of 80 mm.The units will trigger at 0.25 second intervals giving a total time for the wave motion of around about 33 seconds. Broadly my goal.

So thanks again for your input .
Best Tony

Hi Brian

Ive taken your advice and ordered a dozen units to play around with to see if my  ideas using the AC plus capacitor will work or if I need to go to plan B  converting all 120 units to DC motors - a lot of work . I acknowledge that DC is easier particularly from the point of managing power requirements but the scheme is a trade  off .
I’ll let you know how I get on although it will be 6 weeks before I receive the units to play with .
Best
Tony

Comment: honestly, ask a professional electrician to plan and build it. Somebody who states by himself to have little to no skills with such applications should not plan to build something with 100-120A (120*0,8A). Also you should be more explicit, do the motors to be controlled separately, all same speed - same direction,...? All mounted nearby or longer cable distances,... All these points need to be considered

Comment: Or buy one and get it working to your satisfaction. Then buy the other 119.

Comment: @Tony, if you want to ping someone then you need to use the `@username` (with no spaces) format.

Comment: If you're just driving your linear actuators from limit to limit what led you to choose stepper motors? Small DC permanent magnet motors would be simpler to drive and could be cheaper. If you do need to use computer control are you familiar with the Arduino range of computer boards? They were invented specifically to allow easy automation of animated arts projects.

Comment: Steppers really aren't a good choice for this application; you can readily couple other sorts of motors to a leadscrew too, using shaft couplings or even plastic tubing as a coupling.  Even if you were going to use steppers, mucking around with a mains AC solution would not make sense; you'd be better off with a single driver and some sort of relay-based enable scheme.

Comment: "wave action"? what sort of distance/time were you hoping for?  Steppers are stereotypically *slow*; they make sense only where precision is needed but feedback too expensive.

Comment: DC motor linear actuators are widely available but they do generally seem to be enclosed units with an operating rod extending from one end. If your mechanical design prefers an open load screw and follower nut they are generally stepper motor designs. Check before using the AC transformer and capacitor drive that it provides sufficient torque compared to using a proper stepper motor driver.